# Comparing two directories, which one has the newest version of each file?

Tags: php, linux, diff

I have spent a lot of time searching for the solution. I know it there has to be a published solution, I've just been unable to find it.

I have a live directory (Dir1) and a development (Dir2) directory with the same file names. The content may or may not be different and the same goes for the dates.

Using PHP or linux command line, I need to get a recursive list of which directory has the newest version of each file. I can't use rsync because of my hosting environment.

This will give a nice list of the latest modified files for one directory:

`find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM: %Tz %p\n'| sort -n | tail -n20`

The downfall to that is I have to manually compart the output.

This is good, but it doesn't show which files are newer:

`diff --brief -rq www/dashboard dev.efit.health/dashboard`

Is there a way to use diff and have the output show which files are newer?

If not, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show sample input and sample desired output. What should happen if a file only exists in one directory? What should happen if a file exists in both directories and both have same timestamp but have different content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two hierarchies of files rooted in `dir1` and `dir2`, where each hierarchy contains exactly the same set of filenames, you can use a variant of your find command to list the newer of each pair of files.

This code will print one file at random if their timestamps match but you could choose some other behaviour by appropriate filtering.

```
shownewer(){
    find "$1"/ "$2"/ -type f -printf '%T@   :%p\n' |\
    sort -r |\
    sort -t/ -s -k2,2 |\
    sed 's/^[0-9.]*   ://;n;d'
}
```

- `find` prints files with their timestamp (fractional seconds since epoch)
- the first `sort` orders by timestamp in reverse
- the second `sort` ignores the toplevel directory and sorts by the remaining section of the path
- `sed` prints the first file of each pair

**Warning:** The output may be completely wrong if the folders do not contain **exactly** the same set of files. A single deletion could really mess things up.

Test with something like:

```
# create test data
$ mkdir dir1 dir2
$ touch {dir1,dir2}/{1,2,3,4,5}
$ sleep 1
$ touch dir1/2 dir2/{3,5}

$ shownewer dir1 dir2
dir2/1
dir1/2
dir2/3
dir2/4
dir2/5
```

Comment: Thank you. When I run:
```find dev.efit.health/dashboard/ www/dashboard/ -type f -printf '%T@ :%p\n' |\ sort -r |\ sort -t/ -s -k2,2 |\ uniq -u -w24 |\ sed 's/^[0-9.]* ://;n;d'```

I get this:

```bash:  sort: command not found
bash:  sort: command not found
bash:  uniq: command not found
bash:  sed: command not found```

I googled the errors but haven't found a reason that seems to be relevant.
Any ideas?

Comment: you didn't type return after each backslash. Also my printf and sed arguments have 3 spaces before the colon (the length needs to match the `-w` argument to uniq.

Comment: actually the uniq part is broken in some situations. probably simplest just to elide it and print one file of duplicate pairs at random